# Gracefully handling xml api that returns error or success responses

Tags: c#, xml

I am working with a third party XML api, which can only respond to api calls with a `error` or `success` xml response.

For example, here's an `error` xml response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<error>
    <message>
        <![CDATA[Unable to load XML document from resource ]]>
    </message>
    <exception>org.impalaframework.exception.ExecutionException</exception>
    <detail>
        <![CDATA[stack trace here... snipped]]>
    </detail>
</error>
```

and a sample `success` response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<success>
    <message>
        <![CDATA[Order successfully imported ]]>
    </message>
</success>
```

I have he following api wrapper class written:

```
public class ApiConnection
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Private class objects.
    /// </summary>
    private string apiUrl, apiUser, apiPass;

    /// <summary>
    /// Class constructor.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="_apiUrl"></param>
    /// <param name="_apiUser"></param>
    /// <param name="_apiPass"></param>
    public ApiConnection(string _apiUrl, string _apiUser, string _apiPass)
    {
        // Remember settings
        apiUrl = _apiUrl;
        apiUser = _apiUser;
        apiPass = _apiPass;
    }

    // todo: implement SyncNewOrder method
}
```

I want to implement this `SyncNewOrder` method, however knowing the api, the response could be success type or an error type.

What would be the best way to gracefully handle the api response (success or error).

So, I attempted the implementation like this:

```
public class ApiConnection
{
    // ... snipped ...

    public NewOrderResponse SyncNewOrder(NewOrderRequest newOrderRequest)
    {
        // login at api

        // call api with newOrderRequest
        // xml response string stored in: apiResult

        // check if response string contains the word 'error'
        if (apiResult.Contains("error"))
        {
            // Handle error response
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Error));
            using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(apiResult))
            {
                Error error = (Error)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
                return new NewOrderResponse()
                {
                    IsError = true,
                    ErrorMsg = error.Message
                };
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // Handle success response
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Success));
            using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(apiResult))
            {
                Success success = (Success)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
                return new NewOrderResponse()
                {
                    IsError = false,
                    Result = success.Message
                };
            }
        }
    }
}

public class NewOrderResponse
{
    bool IsError { get; set; }
    string ErrorMsg { get; set; }
    string Result { get; set; }
}

public class NewOrderRequest
{
    // ...
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName="error")]
public class Error
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName="message")]
    public string Message { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName="exception")]
    public string Exception { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName="detail")]
    public string Detail { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName="success")]
public class Success 
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName="message")]
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

Would this be considered the correct implementation to handle variable response (success/error)? Or is there a better/correct way to implement this?

Comment: Does it work as intended? Also, you'll get better responses if you include the full, actual code - this isn't Stack Overflow, we don't care about "being specific about a specific issue" - in fact we'd much rather see your code in its full glory, including the "snipped" parts.

Answer (score 5):

This coding style is unusual for C#:

```
private string apiUrl, apiUser, apiPass;
```

The standard is to have one per line:

```
private string apiUrl;
private string apiUser;
private string apiPass;
```

---

Why the `api` prefix in `apiUrl`, `apiUser`, `apiPass`? The class is already called `ApiConnection`.

---

Underscores in front of variable names are only used for fields, not parameters. So this is doing it wrong:

```
public ApiConnection(string _apiUrl, string _apiUser, string _apiPass)
{
    // Remember settings
    apiUrl = _apiUrl;
    apiUser = _apiUser;
    apiPass = _apiPass;
}
```

---

To me it seems like `SyncNewOrder` does too much. Moreover, there is code duplication. It seems to me you can move some of it to a method like this:

```
private T GetValue<T>(string apiResult)
{
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
    using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(apiResult))
    {
        return (T)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
    }
}
```

That way you can reduce your code to something like this:

```
    if (apiResult.Contains("error"))
    {
        var error = GetValue<Error>(apiResult);
        return new NewOrderResponse()
        {
            IsError = true,
            ErrorMsg = error.Message
        };
    }
    else
    {
        var success = GetValue<Success>(apiResult);
        return new NewOrderResponse()
        {
            IsError = false,
            Result = success.Message
        };
    }
```

I'm sure that code can be improved even more, considering there's still duplication.

---

Always explicitly state the access modifiers. I should not need to figure out myself what the scope of `IsError` etc will be.

```
public class NewOrderResponse
{
    bool IsError { get; set; }
    string ErrorMsg { get; set; }
    string Result { get; set; }
}
```

---

Comments like `// Handle success response` are superfluous. Your code should tell me what it does, comments are used to tell me why it was implemented like this (if necessary).